# Using ADXL345 accelerometer sensor with ESP8266

Tags: accelerometer, esp8266, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

I am extremely new to working with sensors and Arduino and IoT equipment altogether. I am using an Arduino Uno. I need to use an ADXL345 sensor with an ESP8266 Wifi module for a project.  The two devices work on their own just fine. But when I connect them together, with the Generic ESP8266 Module board, the ADXL345 does not get detected.

I am using the 2.5.0 version of the ESP8266 library as that's the only one that seems to work with both the ESP8266 and the ADXL345 sensor.

Below is my code -

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADXL345_U.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

/* Assign a unique ID to this sensor at the same time */
Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified accel = Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified(12345);

char ssid[] = "ssid";   // your network SSID (name) 
char pass[] = "pass";   // your network password
int keyIndex = 0;            // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)
WiFiClient  client;

void displayDataRate(void)
{
  Serial.print  ("Data Rate:    "); 
  
  switch(accel.getDataRate())
  {
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_3200_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("3200 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_1600_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("1600 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_800_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("800 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_400_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("400 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_200_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("200 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_100_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("100 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_50_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("50 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_25_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("25 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_12_5_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("12.5 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_6_25HZ:
      Serial.print  ("6.25 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_3_13_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("3.13 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_1_56_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("1.56 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_0_78_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("0.78 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_0_39_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("0.39 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_0_20_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("0.20 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_DATARATE_0_10_HZ:
      Serial.print  ("0.10 "); 
      break;
    default:
      Serial.print  ("???? "); 
      break;
  }  
  Serial.println(" Hz");  
}

void displayRange(void)
{
  Serial.print  ("Range:         +/- "); 
  
  switch(accel.getRange())
  {
    case ADXL345_RANGE_16_G:
      Serial.print  ("16 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_RANGE_8_G:
      Serial.print  ("8 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_RANGE_4_G:
      Serial.print  ("4 "); 
      break;
    case ADXL345_RANGE_2_G:
      Serial.print  ("2 "); 
      break;
    default:
      Serial.print  ("?? "); 
      break;
  }  
  Serial.println(" g");  
}

void setup(void) 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  Serial.println("Accelerometer Test"); Serial.println("");

   delay(5000);
  
  /* Initialise the sensor */
  if(!accel.begin())
  {
    /* There was a problem detecting the ADXL345 ... check your connections */
    Serial.println("Ooops, no ADXL345 detected ... Check your wiring!");
    while(1);
  }

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

   delay(5000);

  /* Set the range to whatever is appropriate for your project */
  accel.setRange(ADXL345_RANGE_16_G);
  // accel.setRange(ADXL345_RANGE_8_G);
  // accel.setRange(ADXL345_RANGE_4_G);
  // accel.setRange(ADXL345_RANGE_2_G);
  
  /* Display additional settings (outside the scope of sensor_t) */
  displayDataRate();
  displayRange();
  Serial.println("");
}

void loop(void) 
{
  // Connect or reconnect to WiFi
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
      WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);  // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(5000);     
    } 
    Serial.println("\nConnected.");
  }

  
  /* Get a new sensor event */ 
  sensors_event_t event; 
  accel.getEvent(&event);
 
  /* Display the results (acceleration is measured in m/s^2) */
  Serial.print("X: "); Serial.print(event.acceleration.x); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("Y: "); Serial.print(event.acceleration.y); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("Z: "); Serial.print(event.acceleration.z); Serial.print("  ");Serial.println("m/s^2 ");
  delay(500);
}
```

The circuit connections are as follows -

ESP8266--

- TX - Arduino TX (D1),
- RX - Arduino RX (D0),
- 3.3V - Arduino 3.3V,
- GND - Arduino GND,
- CH_PD - Arduino 3.3V,
- GPIO0 - Arduino GND,
- GPIO2 - No connection,
- RST - No connection

ADXL345 --

- VCC - Arduino 5V,
- GND - Arduino GND,
- SDA - Arduino SDA,
- SCL - Arduino SCL

ARDUINO UNO --

- RESET - Arduino GND

Can someone please, explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The code you posted looks like code that runs on the ESP8266, not the Uno. Please edit the question to clarify how you have the the Uno, ESP8266 and ADXL345 connected.

Comment: @romkey I have added the connections to the question.
And yes, the code runs on the ESP8266 as I cannot connect to the Wifi without the ESP8266 which requires me to run the whole thing on the Generic ESP8266 MOdule board.

Comment: If the ADXL345 is connected to the Arduino, then how are you expecting code on the ESP8266 to be able to access it?

Comment: @jasonharper I just presumed that since both are connected to the Arduino, the ESP8266 would just detect the ADXL345 via that. Is that not how it is supposed to work? And if not, how am I supposed to do it? I am sorry if I am missing something fairly obvious. This is the very first time I am dealing with IoT coding.

Comment: The Arduino doesn't do ANYTHING you haven't specifically programmed it to do.  Programming it to pass through the ADXL345 communications is certainly possible - but the library you're using would have no idea how to detect or use such a remote connection, so would require extensive modification.  (I have no idea why you even have an Arduino at all, rather than connecting everything directly to the ESP8266.)

Comment: @jasonharper I learnt to use the ESP8266 and the ADXL345 separately using an Arduino Uno. Now, my project reuqires them to be used together. So, I just figured I'd use the Arduino as a "common ground". The ESP8266 I am using is just a Wifi module. It is not connected to a NodeMCU. So, I have no clue as to how even omitting the Arduino would work as the ESP8266 does not have any SDA or SCL pins. Also, I'm using the Arduino as a power source.
I understand wat you're saying about not coding the Uno specifically. I'm just trying to mesh stuff I have learnt separately, which is why I am strugglin.

Comment: The ESP8266 does have SCL and SDA - these support the I2C protocol, which is used to talk to the ADXL345. The module you're using may not express those pins. As @jasonharper said, the Arduino isn't going to do anything for you if you don't write software to make it do it, sorry. You're better off getting a more capable ESP8266 module, or you can run your code on the Arduino and flash the ESP8266 with the [AT firmware](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/release-v2.2.0.0_esp8266/AT_Binary_Lists/index.html) and using it as a wifi modem for the Arduino.

Comment: @romkey Will it be easier for me overall if I just forget about Arduino and just use a ESP8266 NodeMcu with the ADXL345? Because the ADXL345 is my main focus here.

Comment: You can actually use ESP-01 for I2C with GPIO0 as SDA, and GPIO2 as SCL, and initialise with `wire.begin(0, 2)`. You may need pull-up resistors on those lines too.

Comment: @hcheung I tried the way you said, except for the pull-up resistors part, as I don't have any and the expenses are already over budget for me. But thank you for the suggestion.